# Using find in bash script - how to handle case where find returns "file or directory does not exist"

Tags: bash, find

I'm using the find command in my bash script like so

```
for x in `find ${1} .....`;
do
    ...
done
```

However, how do I handle the case where the input to my script is a file/directory that does not exist? (ie I want to print a message out when that happens)

I've tried to use -d and -f, but the case I am having trouble with is when ${1} is "." or ".."

When the input is something that doesn't exist it does not enter my for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have to use `find filename`, you can compare the exit status i.e. `if [ $? != 0 ]; then ...`

Comment: Tried your suggestion Usman and it didn't work. I think that the exist status is still 0 if it can't find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash scripting is a bit weird. Practice before implementation.  But [this site](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) seems to break it down well.

If the file exists, this works:

```
if [ -e "${1}" ]
then
  echo "${1} file exists."
fi
```

If the file does not exist, this works. Note the '!' to denote 'not':

```
if [ ! -e "${1}" ]
then
  echo "${1} file doesn't exist."
fi
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the case I am having trouble with is when ${1} is "." or ".." - the -f, -d and -e options in bash don't work well with "." or ".."

Comment: Never mind tried it again.. -f and -d do not account for "." and ".." but -e does!

Answer (score 2):

Bash gives you this out of the box:

```
if [ ! -f ${1} ];
then
    echo "File/Directory does not exist!"
else
    # execute your find...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

assign the find to a variable and test against the variable.

```
files=`find ${1} .....`
if [[ "$files" != “file or directory does not exist” ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: As above, the case I am having trouble with is when ${1} is "." or ".." - the -f, -d and -e options in bash don't work well with "." or ".."

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
y=`find . -name "${1}"`
if [ "$y" != "" ]; then
  for x in $y; do
    echo "found $x"
  done
else
  echo "No files/directories found!"
fi
```